# How to determine whether a process would run out-of-memory?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory, resources

A testsuite has a couple of tests, that will consume a quite a lot of memory (11GB) or so.
This is typically not a problem when running those tests on my developer machine, but within the context of CI the testsuite is oftentimes executed on machine that don't have that much RAM available.

When the CI-host lacks enough memory, my testsuite is stopped by the OOMkiller, thus failing.

Rather than completely failing the entire test-suite, i would like to limit the tests that are run based on the characteristics of the host machine.

The idea is to use valgrind's `massif` tool to get an approximation of how much memory will be consumed by a given test, then check how much memory is available on the host, and skip those tests that would exceed this memory.

However, I have the gut feeling that finding out "how much memory is available" is a non-trivial task.

- I cannot control on which runners the CI is going to be executed (and there might be different ones with different amounts of available RAM)
- On the runners, I am not `root`, and thus have little/no control over *OOMkiller* itself
- The runners are most likely just docker containers running on some random cloud provider (Who is in control of OOMkiller in this case? the container? the host?)

Just parsing `/proc/meminfo` seems a bit too naive

- does that give me the memory available within the container?
- `MemAvailable` seems like a good choice, but even on my 32GB-RAM desktop this currently shows only 10GB of available memory and I can still run a process that consumes **11GB** of memory (afaict `MemAvailable` ignores available swapspace)

Obviously the system is dynamic, and while there might be enough available memory when I start my test, other processes might consume memory during the test's runtime, so I could still run out-of-memory

So:
How should I tackle this problem?
Is there a way to query the OOMkiller for my allowance of memory?

Comment: As you say, `MemAvailable` ignores swap — its purpose is to indicate how much memory can be used without forcing the system to use swap.

Comment: which is probably a good metric if you want your process to finish anytime soon :-) but the real issue is: within the container, will this give me the limit allocated to my cgroup?